# Favicon backup for `msapplication-TileImage` on Windows 8.

Tags: html, windows-8, favicon

I have a simple yes/no question.

If I don't put this in my HTML file:

```
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="favicon.png">
```

Will Windows 8 automatically use this PNG:

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.png">
```

I don't have a Windows 8 machine to test it.

Answer (score 18):

The simple answer is yes, it will use the favicon.

With that said, it may not display in the most optimal fashion.

Here is a screenshot with a test I ran:

[image: Favicon Test on Windows 8]

***Update***

My answer that I originally posted is still valid but there is a better way:

**Custom Tiles for IE 11+ on Windows 8.1+**

IE 11+ on Windows 8.1+ does offer a way to create pinned tiles for your site.

Microsoft recommends creating a few tiles at the following size:

> Small: 128 x 128
>
> Medium:    270 x 270
>
> Wide: 558 x 270
>
> Large: 558 x 558

These should be transparent images as we will define a color background next.

Once these images are created you should create an xml file called `browserconfig.xml` with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<browserconfig>
  <msapplication>
    <tile>
      <square70x70logo src="images/smalltile.png"/>
      <square150x150logo src="images/mediumtile.png"/>
      <wide310x150logo src="images/widetile.png"/>
      <square310x310logo src="images/largetile.png"/>
      <TileColor>#009900</TileColor>
    </tile>
  </msapplication>
</browserconfig>
```

Save this xml file in the root of your site. When a site is pinned IE will look for this file. For additional information on IE 11+ custom tiles and using the XML file [visit Microsoft's website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn455106%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

***Old Answer***

The best way to incorporate a favicon for Windows 8 is to use the following code:

```
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#D83434">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="path/to/tileicon.png">
```

The first line is the tile color, you can use a hex value, RGB or a CSS color name. The second line is the path to the icon. For best results the icon should be transparent and sized at 144x144 pixels.

Comment: In the .xml the smallest size is 70x70 and in your quote: Microsoft recommends Small: 128x128. So which one is it? Similarly for other sizes?

Comment: The short answer is both. From the link above: "Standard tile dimensions=70x70", "Recommended image size=128x128". The difference is the tile size vs. the image size.